# Execute GET _mapping Elasticsearch API using a previously filtered documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to restrict GET _mapping request results, return field names based on a filtered list of document?

Something about:

```
GET /pets/_mapping
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "family": {
        "query": "felines"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

On documentation there isn't this feature.

Example:

Doc 1

```
{
"family": "felines",
"name" : "Simba"
}
```

Doc 2

```
{
"family": "felines",
"name" : "Nala"
}
```

Doc 3

```
{
"family": "dogs",
"nickname" : "Lilli"
}
```

Doc 4

```
{
"family": "dogs",
"nickname" : "Pluto"
}
```

For family = "felines" it should return

```
[family, name]
```

For family = "dogs" it should return

```
[family, nickname]
```

Thanks!

Comment: The mapping is per index, not per document, so all documents in the `pets` index have the same mapping

Comment: @Val thanks for your answer, but we have differents mapping structure inside the same index... The same structure is identified by a value of a specific field, so we have to pre-filter that field, and then extract mapping

Comment: It is usually not advised to store different entity mappings in the same index because that can lead to [mapping explosion](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings). You'd be much better off having different indexes for each entity. The gain would be that you'd know exactly the mapping of each index and using an alias you can query all the indexes as if they were in the same index.